# Prometheus query - exclude destination

Tags: grafana, prometheus

On my ActiveMQ I have some Queues, which end with .error. On a Grafana Dashboard I want to list all queues without these .error-queues.
Example:

```
some.domain.one
some.domain.one.error
some.domain.two
some.domain.two.error
```

To list all queues I use this query:

```
org_apache_activemq_localhost_QueueSize{Type="Queue",Destination=~"some.domain.*",}
```

How do I exclude all .error-queues?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a negative regex matcher: `org_apache_activemq_localhost_QueueSize{Type="Queue",Destination=~"some.domain.*",Destination!~".*\.error"}`

Comment: Cool, thx. I did not know that I can specify destinations more often. this works for me now: `org_apache_activemq_localhost_ConsumerCount{Type="Queue",Destination=~"some.domain.*",Destination!~".*error"}`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a bit more simpler way to exclude multiple endings:

```sh
org_apache_activemq_localhost_QueueSize{Type="Queue",Destination!~".*error|.*warn"}
```

`!~`: not include the quoted string
`|` : it is `or`